# How do I get a Mongoose.Schema property from inside a Express.Router.post()? (+send a Firebase notification)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried this code to send a Firebase notification when posting data to my remote DB, using a hardcoded Registration Token, it worked (notification + storage) :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Offer = require('../models/offer');

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "This is a Notification",
      body: "This is the body of the notification message."
    }
  };

var options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 *24
  };

//exports to my Express.Router.post()
//which is in a different file : router.post('/', OffersController.offers_create_offer);
exports.offers_create_offer = (req, res, next) => {
    const offer = new Offer({
        _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        userId : req.body.userId,
        postId : req.body.postId,
        pricingDetails : req.body.pricingDetails,
        serviceDetails : req.body.serviceDetails
    });

    offer.save().then(result => {
        //my hardcoded Registration Token 
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice("dfs...f49", payload, options)
            .then(function(response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });

        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message : 'Offer created successfully',
            offer : {
                _id : result._id,
                userId : result.userId,
                postId : result.postId,
                pricingDetails : result.pricingDetails,
                serviceDetails : result.serviceDetails
            }
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error : err
        });
    });

};
```

and now I want to get the Token from my user schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true,
        match : /[a-...])?/ 
    },
    password : {type : String, required : true},
    name : {type : String, required : true},
    FCMRegToken : {type : String, required : true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Here is my post body just in case :

```
{
        "userId": "5...c4",
        "postId": "5...2b",
        "pricingDetails" : "pricing",
        "serviceDetails" : "details",
        "jobUserId" : "5...3f"//which is a different userId
}
```

I specifically need to get the FCMRegToken that corresponds to req.body.jobUserId like below :

```
...
const Offer = require('../models/offer');

const User = require('../models/user');
...
exports.offers_create_offer = (req, res, next) => {
    //trying to get the Token
    user = User.findOne({ _id :  req.body.jobUserId});
    FCMRegToken = user.FCMRegToken;
...
    offer.save().then(result => {
        //trying to pass it as an argument
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(FCMRegToken , payload, options)
        .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
```

but it didn't work and i get a warning that my FCMRegToken "must be a non-empty String...", knowing that I checked my DB and made sure that the Token where _id = jobUserId is not empty and correct.

Is there a right way to achieve this goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying somethings I found a way ... more like I understood how queries work in mongoose, here is what worked for me :

```
...
const Offer = require('../models/offer');

const User = require('../models/user');
...
exports.offers_create_offer = (req, res, next) => {
...
    offer.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message : 'Offer created successfully',
            offer : {
                _id : result._id,
                userId : result.userId,
                postId : result.postId,
                pricingDetails : result.pricingDetails,
                serviceDetails : result.serviceDetails
            }
        })
        //trying to get the corresponding user document
        const user = User.findOne({ _id :  req.body.postUserId});
        user.select('_id FCMRegToken')
        .exec()
        .then(doc => {
            //trying to pass the user doc's property FCMRegToken as an argument
            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(doc.FCMRegToken , payload, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
        })
    })
...
```